# Install NuGet package with dependencies into same folder

Tags: powershell, dependencies, nuget

I have a project (a PowerShell module) that relies upon a NuGet package, whose assemblies are loaded into my module via the `Add-Type` cmdlet. I would like to install this package via NuGet instead of manually copying it into the correct folder. This would save me from committing it's binaries to source control. Also: when thinking about CI/CD, I'd hate to have them in my repo.

I know I can curate a `packages.config` file and use `nuget install` instead. But this command installs the package together with it's dependencies into a separate folder and therefore the framework will (runtime) not find the required dependencies.

I know I could also provide a script that performs the `nuget install` and then copies the required `.dll` files into a single folder. But I would have to deal with the fact that the package might have different versions for different target frameworks and I'd need to handle the compatibility. Or maybe the package has other additional required files that I know nothing about.

So here my question: there has got to be a simpler way to do this? Something less ... circuitous and cumbersome?

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Comment: Not really. I have found a much larger-scale workaround by changing the architecture of my product so I don't need to rely on single packages. Nuget by design does not install dependencies of packages. And I really didn't want to reinvent the wheel.